# Mapbox performance suffers after adding 1000+ markers using geojson

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core-mvc, mapbox, mapbox-marker

I am using mapbox to visualize some coordinates along a path. I have a couple of datasets that have a different amounts of coordinates, everything between 5 and 3500 sets of coordinates. I am using a geojson object to draw the markers, but when I choose the data sets that have more than 1000 sets of coordinates my mapbox starts to become unresponsive when I move around the map. If I choose even larger data sets the entire page becomes unresponsive.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.1.1/mapbox.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.1.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
        L.mapbox.accesToken = <access-token>
        var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
            .setView([40, -74.50], 9);

        var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer();
        myLayer.addTo(map)

        var geojson = []

        var jsonData = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));
        $.each(jsonData, function(key, value) {
            geojson.push(addMarker(value.lat, value.lon));
        });

        myLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
            var marker = e.layer,
                feature = marker.feature;
            marker.setIcon(L.divIcon(feature.properties.icon));
        });

        myLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson);
    </script>
</body>
```

The addMarker function basically just creates a single geojson object as follows:

```
function addMarker(latitude, longitude) {

    var element = {
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [longitude, latitude]
        },
        properties: {
            icon: {
                className: "map-icon",
                html: '',
                iconSize: null
            }
        }
    };

    return element;
}
```

I am using .Net Core MVC to get my data from my database. Is there some other way to add markers to Mapbox so that the performance doesn't drop as significantly as it does with my example?

```
.map-icon {
    background: #dd0600;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 5px;
}
```

I don't really do much with the markers, I just want to have colored circles/dots, but I could think this is one of the reasons why the map suffers as it does.

I need this functionality and I know google maps API supports lots of markers without much hit on performance, so I was hoping the same was possible with MapBox. If not I might need to use either Google Maps or some other solution like OpenLayers.

Comment: mapbox-gl symbols are significantly more performant than the HTML-based markers

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Sadly not. I tried numerous different solutions that I could find, but ended up using OpenLayers in the end.